# python shutil.rmtree - how to remove/set timeout?

Tags: python, timeout, settimeout, directory, shutil

Python 2.7, Trying to delete a large folder with shutil.rmtree() yields timeout.
How is it possible to set the timeout or have the operation run until it finishes?

```
File "/var/www/fat/fatsite/analysis_retention/analysis_retention_handler.py", line 29, in delete_old_analysis
    shutil.rmtree(analysis_to_delete.output_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
  File "/home/fat/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/timeouts.py", line 51, in handle_death_penalty
    'value ({0} seconds)'.format(self._timeout))
JobTimeoutException: Job exceeded maximum timeout value (180 seconds)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is an RQ exception.
So it is possible from the Django Admin to set a timeout on the RQ repeatable job object.
[image]